# iFrame access denied remote domain

Tags: ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest

How do i send a JavaScript function to an iframe with external content loaded,

eg

> onclick="getElementByID('myiframe').src='fun();'"

is there a way with ajax, i think **XMLHttpRequest** can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's a security feature

Answer (score 0):

everything must be on the same domain. or you will need to setup a proxy

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier you cannot do this because of the builtin security model of the browsers.

However, if the two sites are hosted on the same subdomain, for example appA.company.com and appB.company.com, you can get around it using domain relaxation. 
All you have to do is to set the document.domain in both pages to company.com.
See http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/ for more information